# css hover does not work

Tags: css, hover

I know it is very easy question but I cannot do it. I need add a:hover, but it does not work. 
Here is html

```
<a href="/sport" data-placement="right" rel="tooltip" class="category_item">
            <p class="">Спорт и активный отдых</p>
</a>
```

and in css I try:

```
a.category_item:hover;
.category_item a:hover
```

But they don work. Do I do anything wrong?

Comment: That should work. Can you show some more css code?

Comment: You haven't put much though into your question, for example a.category_item:hover could at least be an actual css rule like a.category_item:hover{text-decoration:underline;} so that stack users can better understand your goals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you want when hovering over a?
This is an example of your hovering:

```
a.category_item:hover p {
   color: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be change and try this:

```
a.category_item p:hover{
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to try like this

```
.category_item > p:hover
{
 background-color:yellow;
}
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/9LXDE/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with below css it will work for you. [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/AWmwB/)

```
a.category_item:hover{
    color:#f10e0e;
}
```